# How to find the radius of convergence of such series

Tags: real-analysis

To find the radius of convergence of such series
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{e^{2 i\pi nz}}{(n+1)^{2/3}}$$
Since $z$ is a complex number, I can simply write it into $z = x + iy$
Hence, I have $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{e^{2 i\pi nx} e^{-2 \pi ny}}{(n+1)^{2/3}}$$
My logic is: in order to compute the radius of convergence, I need to separate $x$ and $y$ out of the $a_n$, then I can have the form $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n z^n$$
Then we can simply compute the radius of convergence $$\rho = \frac {1} {\lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \sup \sqrt[n]{||a_n||} }$$I don't know how to separate $a_n$ and $z^n$, or perhaps I'm on the wrong track? Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: The series is not a power series, so it does not _have_ a radius of convergence. (Is your post _exactly_ what the problem asked?)

Comment: The original question was to find the region of convergence of such series. So, I suppose in order to find the region, we need to find the radius of the disc first?

Comment: Yes or no, depending on what you mean. What disk are you referring to?

Comment: The shape of the region a power series converges is always a disc, isn't this always true?

Comment: As you mentioned earlier, this isn't a power series, hence, we cannot find the radius of convergence, but in order to find the region of convergence what other method can we apply here? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The series is not a power series. But $\sum w^n/(n+1)^{2/3}$ is a power series. You can find the radius of convergence of the second series. That tells you where the second series converges. And _then_ you can use _that_ to find where the original series converges. (The region where the original series converges is not a diisk.)